# Excel: Adding a Connector Line In a Chart (Have to Use a Macro)?

Tags: formatting, excel, charts, excel-2003, vba

So I'm working on this chart in Excel, and the chart looks like two sides of a triange, like the picture at the link below:

http://a.imageshack.us/img832/6207/triangle.png.

I'd like to make a line (like, with an autoshape for example) that connects the 2 endpoints to form a triange; ie a line going from coordinates (4,1) to (4,5).  I tried doing this by creating a seperate data series in excel with the coordinates of the connecting line, like:

4,1 
4,2 
4,3 
4,4 
4,5

However, in excel, all lines in this chart must have the same x coordinates.  Does anyone know how to get a connecting line automatically?  Say, with a macro or something?  Reason I ask is because I want to be able to change these coordinates, and I want the connecting line to adjust with very little effort (ideally I could write a macro and assign it to a button that when you click it would adjust the connecting line).  I have some very limited macro experience, but this is just beyond me.  The type of chart I'm using is a standard line chart, where the description given by excel is "Displays trends over time or categories".  Anyone know of a good resource or have some advice? Thanks.

PS I solved this problem by changing the chart type to a scatter chart, but this messed up the axes and scale, and required that those be adjusted, so I think adding a line in this manner automatically will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

The scatter chart worked OK.
Used formulas included in the following image.
Perhaps you should include an image showing the problems you found.

[image]